# RSA vulnerability when e is particularily large?

Tags: rsa

I'm trying to solve a problem that goes like this:

> c:
> 3627012278341906638812055223389930986183534985985788329485858567557776422481803764253822727571579721298297507294021402712610264908031407416536130863074328807753848481071241506052292677974569848935466918445359356828655429344756595758706102715670649052786530127013616969520602108058338174594919786658238254244
>
> n:
> 56408147735425453769001580679058631793488956756290710409405554427030825848723837389920261733726883964738560861161368073398240019980428844626276432710534329907155342315282276112954512741477124225287943755138234375599478885404610626929884276937517857848674917362363510326343239899011267973451815054982495415687
>
> e:
> 13003559759934201375437934005206491129225188194058929350829289047157814927789183747912100252882276621439342317933777085507432598713159268575213762384466063887128254080879340183824577621864138933615008301844717727025642074116345682287129320641392013567214116634743103750889601181922862069484721072292458609313
>
> Find m

What I'm noticing is that $e$ is large, extremely large. I don't know if the rule of choosing $e$ so that $1 < e < \varphi(n)$ is applicable with the $e$ value I'm given. Either way, is there some kind of exploit with an $e$ value this large?

Normal values of e are things like 3 or 65537. Does e being this massive number say anything about the rest of the variables $(p, q, d, etc)$?

Comment: If a secure key pair generator has been used I think this is secure; I've seen HSM's allow such public exponents (although I'm not sure if that was certified FIPS mode). That is isn't very efficient is certain: the public exponent is as big as the private exponent and CRT parameters are (obviously) not available for public key calculations. As many implementations do not allow such public exponents it is a compatibility issue as well.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Compatibility issue? can you explain this a bit more? I don't have the right to choose my $e$ not freely other than the most common $e$?

Comment: Since this is a problem, my first idea; the questioner replaced the e with the d
second; try small message space, like up to 8 or 10 characters.

Comment: @kelalaka See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474550/is-there-a-limit-for-rsa-key-exponents-in-net) for a 32 bit limitation of the public exponent. Yeah, if this is a problem for which a solution must exist then the issue is no doubt *related to* the public exponent / key generation. However, that doesn't mean that a large public exponent is a problem *by itself*. It no doubt a problem in the $\text{Gen}$ function.

Comment: $d$ might be small and you can try the special attacks that exist in that case.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Wiener's attack.